# How to Pass to many records as parameter to a SP in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

I'm truncating a table(Say 'X' table ) and inserting values on some conditions into that.Then after i have to select those inserted values,
and delete those in another table(say 'Y' table),which is present in other server by executing a stored proc(say delrec).This all should be done in SSIS package.

but the table 'X' contains many records.How to pass all those records as parameters to 'delrec' procedure in SSIS ?

Comment: Are you inserting with a data flow?

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass them as a parameter.

Insert them into a staging table on the second server, and reference that staging table in the `delrec` procedure.